Equality in Jensen Inequality with Convex Function
Jensen's inequality states that for a convex function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $n$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathrm{Dom}f$, and positive numbers $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ that sum to 1, there is
$$
f(\lambda_1 x_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n x_n)  \leq \lambda_1 f(x_1) + \ldots + \lambda_n f(x_n)
$$
Now, I have a function that always takes equality in the inequality but only for points under certain restrictions. For example, I know that if we restrict the points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, equality still implies $f$ is linear. However, if I have that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,
$$
f \left( \frac{x+ \frac{1}{n}+ x-\frac{1}{n} }{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}f \left( x+ \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{2}f \left( x-\frac{1}{n}\right) 
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, can I conclude that $f$ is linear? More generally, for a function that satisfies equality in Jensen's inequality with some restrictions, I want to know when we can conclude that $f$ is linear.

Just to clarify: here "linear" means "affine", i.e. $f(x) = a x + b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb R$.
Suppose $f$ is a convex function and there is some $r > 0$ such that
$$ f(x) = \frac{f(x-r) + f(x+r)}{2} \ \text{for all}\ x \in \mathbb R$$
Let $ b = f(0)$ and $a = (f(r) - f(0))/r $.  Thus $f(r) = a r + b$.
By induction we can prove that $f(k r) = a k r + b$ for all integers $k$.
Now for any $x \in \mathbb R$, there is $k$ such that $k r \le x < (k+1) r$.
We have $x = \alpha kr + (1-\alpha) (k+1) r$ where $\alpha = ((k+1)r - x)/r$
so $f(x) \le \alpha f(kr) + (1-\alpha) f((k+1)r) = ax + b$, while
$(k+1) r = \beta x +  (1-\beta) (k+2) r$ where $\beta = r/((k+2)r - x)$ so
$ f((k+1) r) \le \beta f(x) + (1-\beta) f((k+2)r) $
which says $$ f(x) \ge \frac{(f((k+1) r) - (1-\beta) f((k+2)r)}{\beta} = a x + b$$
and we conclude $f(x) = ax + b$, i.e. $f$ is linear.
